# EntityFramwork 6 table not created with CreateDatabaseIfNotExists

Tags: entity-framework

When setting the initialization to CreateDatabaseIfNotExists,
I noticed that if the DB exists BUT the table doesn't, it will not be created.

In this case, the DB has multiple unrelated tables and I need EntityFramework to create the table if it is not present, or use it, if it is present. DropCreateDatabaseAlways is, obviously, not an option either because it will destroy other tables in the same database.

Comment: Please, add more info to your question, for example what are doing in your context?

Comment: Sorry for the formatting, for some reason, it doesn't keep it when I save my edits..

For example, I have a database called 'Tools' with the following tables: Settings and Directory.

I have a tool, using EF6, that has a class 'Setting' and will uniquely use the 'Settings' table.

If the database 'Tools' is created and has the table 'Directory' already in place, then CreateDatabaseIfNotExists will fail because the database is already in place and it will NOT create the table 'Settings'.

Because multiple tools write to the same database, I need to initialize only the table, not the database.

Answer (score 1):

```
 public MyDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection")
        {
            Database.SetInitializer(new SeedMyDbContext());
            Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
        }

 public class SeedMyDbContext : CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<MyDbContext>
        {
            protected override void Seed(MyDbContext context)
            {
               //Your code goes here (dummy data seeding)
               base.Seed(context);
            }
        }
```

I am  using like this for create tables.

And also migrations for update-database. I hope that'll work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do what you are up to (as per your comment) with the `CreateDatabaseIfNotExists` initializer. You may need to create your own custom initializer or maybe use Migrations.

Comment: yes, it looks like it; everything I find on the net is related to migration. Because I'm new to EF, I haven't looked into that yet.

Answer (score 0):

Use the initializer MigrateToLatestVersion to add new tables etc.
eg

```
  Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<MyDbContext, MyMigrationConfiguration>());
  myContext.Database.Initialize(true);
```

The migration Config Class....

```
  // use a base migration config class to control

public class MyMigrationConfiguration : BosBaseMigrationConfiguration<BosSystemDbContext> {
    // specific action for this context and migration??? maybe...
  }        


    // keep it consistent here
  public abstract class MyBaseMigrationConfiguration<TContext> : DbMigrationsConfiguration<TContext> 
    where TContext  : DbContext{

    protected  MyBaseMigrationConfiguration() {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;  // you can still chnage this later if you do so before triggering Update
        AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true; // you can still chnage this later if you do so before triggering Update

    }
    protected override void Seed(TContext context)
    {
        base.Seed(context);  // but i dont like this approach to seeding
    }

}
```